# Delete 2 chars in a row

Tags: php

First, I want to shorten this variable (`$output`) value length to 15 characters then I want to check if two chars are identical in a row and delete the last char and set `$i-1` but idk why it is not working, for example:

**output**: `ahsgtyy2wer8utu`

**desired**: `ahsgty2wer8utu`

**desired** is to remove the repeated char if there is two consecutive chars are identical:

```
$pat='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789';
$z=0;
$output='';
for($i=0;$i<15;$i++)
{
    $output.=$pat[mt_rand(0,strlen($pat)-1)];
    if($output[$i]==$output[$i-1])
    {
        $output=rtrim($output,$output[strlen($output)-1]);
        $i=$i-1;
    }

}
echo $output;
echo "<BR>".rtrim($output,$output[strlen($output)-1]);
```

Comment: Please can You provide an example of input data and desired output data?

Comment: @RomanHocke i edit my Question dude or do you want  me to comment the example here ?

Comment: do you want to delete duplicate caracter ?

Comment: @MHFuad yes just delete the last char of duplicated chars and output length must be 15

Comment: `ahsgty2wer8utu` has length __14__

Comment: @u_mulder yes bro after delete last char of duplicated chars all i want when deleteting this char make $i var which in loop =$i-1 to make this step again and replace this deleted char with another .. if u know what i mean <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from your code you want to generate a random password / string of length 15 ...

a fresh approach for it... (no chance of repetition )

```
$pat='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789';
$arr = str_split($pat);
shuffle($arr);
print substr(implode('',$arr),0, 15);
```

Comment: yea thx man thats exactly what iam looking for <3 thx u all for ur replies i'm appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If You just need to replace sequences of the same character with a single character, You can do it like this:

```
// original input string
$input = 'ahsgtyy2wer8utu';

// result string with removed sequences of the same character
$result = '';

// remember last character to compare it to current one
$last = '';
$length = strlen($input);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {

    // get current character of input string
    $current = $input[$i];

    // if it is different character than the last one, add it to the result
    if ($current !== $last) {

        $result .= $current;
        $last = $current;
    }

    // ... otherwise do not add nothing to result string
}

// $result now contains "ahsgty2wer8utu"
```